# Jasmine test help needed afterEach

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I have a logic built using jQuery that uses two each loops. I'm not sure how to write jasmine test for it.

Here is my code/logic:

```
<div id="mj">
  <div class="commonclass">
    Item 1
  </div>
  <div class="commonclass">
    Item 2
  </div>
  <div class="commonclass">
    Item 3
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var filterArray = ['Item', 'Block', 'Item 3'];

$.each($('.commonclass'), function(i, v) {
  var matching = false;
  $.each(filterArray, function(j, w) {
    if ($(v).text().trim() == w)
      matching = true;
  });
  if (matching)
    $(v).remove();
});
```

Logic:

The text from the div elements should not match with the filterarray values. The element should be removed if it is matched.

This is my jasmine test code. (Added partial)

```
describe('Delete matching element', function() {
        beforeAll(function() {
            elementsEl = element(SelectorData.selectors.elementSelector);
            elementValueEl = element(SelectorData.selectors.elementTitleSelector);
            bodyDocumentEl = element(SelectorData.selectors.body);
            bodyDocumentValues = SelectorData.values;
        });

        afterEach( function() {

            if (elementValueEl.value == bodyDocumentValues.value) {
                document.body.removeChild(elementsEl);
            }

        });

        it('delete the element', function() {
            expect(elementsEl.isPresent()).toBe(false);

        });
    });
```

Let me know what am I doing wrong here. 
[JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dmahendranme/g1L2Lzm1/](https://jsfiddle.net/dmahendranme/g1L2Lzm1/)

Comment: Simpler without jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/g1L2Lzm1/1/

Comment: Not related but google `jasmine-jquery` - it's a small library which will help your code stay in sync, therefore accessing jquery objects with jquery in the tests too - just an FYI

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$(function(){    
    var filterArray = ['Item', 'Block', 'Item 3'];
    $('.commonclass').each(function(k,v){        
        if($.inArray($.trim($(v).text()), filterArray) > 0){
            $(this).remove()
        }
    });
});
```